# MySQL query & joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables..

```
devices(id, brand_id, device_name)
brands(id, brand_name)
```

I have a number of brands that do not have a single device in the devices table, I basically want to ignore these brands that do not have at least 1 single device

Using the rows below how would I return the query to only all brands that have an entry in the devices table as they have entries in the devices (with brand_id being the foreign key in the devices table) - would this need a join?

e.g table structure

```
brands table:
id  name
1   apple
2   samsung
3   acme

devices table:
id    brand_id  name
1     1         iphone
2     2         galaxy s4
3     1         ipad

# desired db result #
1 Apple
2 Samsung
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` will let you grab all brands that have a device. We group by brand.id so that brands aren't returned once for every device.

```
SELECT brands.* 
FROM brands
INNER JOIN devices ON (brands.id = devices.brand_id)
GROUP BY brands.id
```

An alternative way would be to use a subquery but I believe the join will be faster:

```
SELECT * 
FROM brands 
WHERE id IN (SELECT brand_id FROM devices);
```

Comment: Thanks Jim - works a treat +1 for the secondary query too will accept shortly

Comment: Indeed the JOIN will be faster if indexes are correctly in use.. IN statements would always require an FULL table on table brands.. so this would scale on large to very large tables.. and you need an good index on brands.id because off the GROUP BY so no temporary table/filesort is needed to handle the results

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need `JOIN` syntax, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  brands.*
FROM
  brands
    LEFT JOIN devices
      ON brands.id=devices.brand_id
WHERE
  devices.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: An Inner join forces the required condition on table A and B, no need for a where IS NOT NULL.  This type of query is typically used in the inverse consideration... I want all things that DO NOT have in a child table and then you would look for where Child.ID IS NULL.